# Cómo puedo Remover el primer caracter en un df de todos los elem de una columna?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Necesito modificar todos los elementos de la 2da columna, de un df de formato: 2col x nfilas (A medida que la BBDD crece, se incorporan filas). La modificación a realizar, es eliminar el lead char, es decir, el primero de la izquierda, y no encuentro cómo hacerlo. Todas las consultas y respuestas mencionan como modificar el df, no los datos contenidos en él. Pensé en utilizar str.lstrip(), pero ésta se utiliza para eliminar caracteres conocidos, y yo desconozco cual será (salvo que permita caracteres comodines, pero no encontré información al respecto). Otro dato, los elementos tienen 4 char y deben quedar en los 3 de la derecha. Estoy intentando también con np, pero todavía no puedo resolverlo. Agradezco si alguien tiene alguna idea, y un saludo muy grande a la comunidad.

Comment: Hola Femaldi, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: He buscando bastante en la web, y casi todas las explicaciones se refieren a modificar el df (añadir columnas, filas, borrar ambas, rellenar con un valor, cero, etc). No encuentro, ni siquiera en la guía de pandas del sitio oficial cómo realizarlo. Puedo asegurar que no es por falta de esfuerzo, e investigación. Estoy aprendiendo programación en forma amateur, soy Ingeniero en Electrónica, desempleado (programo en assembler, Arduino, PLC, Python y HTML5), y agradezco cualquier ayuda, con respecto a esta cuestión. Saludo atte.

Comment: Esto que necesito resolver, no es ningún ejercicio planteado, sino un proyecto propio que estoy elaborando, buscando una forma de generar una idea rentable. A traés de ML

Comment: No se trata de ningún tipo de facilismo. Si es incorrecto pedir ayuda para resolver una inquietud de este tenor, por favor me avisan y borro la consulta y la cuenta.

Comment: He respondido consultas técnicas, dado que he sido técnico oficial Dell, NCR,  Sabre,  Iphone y de reparación de PCs y NB. Por favor revisar

Comment: Hola de nuevo, podrías mostrarnos el código que tienes, y la estructura del df, así se hará más sencillo responder.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Como no pusiste tus datus ni un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) tuve que crear un ejemplo genérico para la respuesta.

Si la columna es de tipo `string` puedes utilizar el accesor `str` y aplicar una [segmentación](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3-es) del `string` que iría desde el caracter `1` hasta el final de la cadena (Recordando que la primera posición es `0` y la segunda es `1`).

Si la columna es de otro tipo, por ejemplo `int` podrías utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) en conjunto con `lambda` para convertir primero el valor de cada "celda" a `string` y luego aplicar la segmentación.

En el ejemplo genérico estoy creando dos nuevas columnas para mostrar los dos métodos, en tu programa puedes asignar el resultado a la misma columna de la que estás leyendo los datos.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1234, 2345, 3456, 4567], 'B': ['ABCD', 'BCDE', 'CDEF', 'DEFG']})

# Eliminar el primer caracter utilizando el accesor str de la columna
df['C'] = df['B'].str[1:]

# Eliminar el primer caracter con apply y lambda
df['D'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[1:])

print(df)
```

Esto imprime:

```
      A     B    C    D
0  1234  ABCD  BCD  234
1  2345  BCDE  CDE  345
2  3456  CDEF  DEF  456
3  4567  DEFG  EFG  567
```

Comment: Agregando a lo dicho por @HeytalePazguato, tambien se puede usar compresion de listas, las cuales, me parece que son un poco mas rapidas:

`%timeit df['B'].str[1:]`
137 µs ± 3.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

`%timeit [str(x)[1:] for x in df['B']]`
6.02 µs ± 429 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: @pythonista_entusiasta, en un `dataset` pequeño puede ser que sea más rápido pero recuerda que los métodos de `pandas` están optimizados para trabajar con `dataframes` habría que ver si en una serie enorme sigue siendo más rápida.